# laravel 5.2 pass parameter to request file for validation

Tags: php, validation, request, laravel-5

i want to implement localization in request file for validation , but in request file just detect en language , i just wan to send locale variable to request file and use in message section just like this :

```
public function messages()
{
    app()->setLocale($locale);

    return [
        'countryName.required' => trans('lang.msg'),
    ];
}
```

i just wan to send $locale to this file when click on submit in my form, i just want to have multi language message
please help me to complete my project
thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to provide the locale after submission? You can do it like this:

```
class AppRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function messages() {
        app()->setLocale( $this->request->get( 'appLocale' ) ?? 'en' );

        return [
            // rules here
        ];
    }
}
```

You have to pass the `appLocale` key along with the submitted data from your form. I included 'en' as a fallback locale. So, somewhere in your HTML form, you have something like this:

```
<input name="appLocale" type="hidden" value="en">
```

Cheers! :)